# Union, trim and save as a new table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 3 tables that have exact same schema and I would like to union/join/merge them all into one big table and save it as combinedtable.

Within each of the 3 tables is the same column that contains a string. The string within this column is prefixed with a "'" which I would like to remove.

I concatenated this character to my string in excel to overcome the scientific notation that excel applied to it. Since I have defined that column as a string in my BigQuery schema I no longer need it and would like to remove it.

SQL or its like is not my thing (yet!), could someone give me an idea how I could do this in BigQuery?

I believe I can do a LTRIM on the column to remove the "'" from the start of the string but I don't know how to piece it all together with the union part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something as simple as below

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(troubled_field, "^'", "") AS fixed_field, 
  second_field, 
  third_field
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

See also more about UNION ALL at [FROM clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from) and about REGEXP_EXTRACT in [Regular expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)

Btw, to see why I use REGEXP_REPLACE vs LTRIM - try below

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("'''abc'def", "^'", ""), LTRIM("'''abc'def", "'")
```

It can be not that important in your particular case though

Simpler version can be

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(troubled_field, 2) AS fixed_field, 
  second_field, 
  third_field
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

Note: this version assumes ALL values in that column starts with "'"
The first version (with REGEXP_REPLACE) is less concurned about this - if some values do not start with "'" they will be just not changed, whereas in second version (with SUBSTR) first character will always be removed even if it is not "'"

See more about [SUBSTR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#substr) function

Use Options section to set destination table and other attributes
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for your quick reply, do I need to write an AS statement to save it to a new table called "combinedtable" with the same schema as the original three tables?

Comment: you can just use "Show Options" button in Web UI to view and fill respective destination attributes - table, write preferences, etc. See addition in my answer

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for your help on this one, it worked perfectly!